# injecting service into angularjs app config

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to inject $http serivce into app config, but getting "unknown provider $http error".

```
    woi.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider','$http', function($routeProvider,      $locationProvider,$http){
$routeProvider
    .when("/channels", {
        templateUrl: test,
        resolve: {
          app: function($http){

         }
        } 

    })
    ]});
```

My question is , is it possible to inject $http serivce in app config ,and if not then what are the  other ways to do ajax call before controller and template is called.

Thanks,

Comment: `$http` does not need to be injected at config function level. You can directly inject it at resolve level as you have done. It would work.

Comment: Adding as answer, so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly pass `$http` or any dependency into the function, without defining it at config function. The DI framework of Angular would inject dependencies for resolve object functions.